# How to count number of tries until correct user input/ make randint change only when user input is equal to randint

Tags: python-3.x, count

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to build a number-guessing game. The problem that I have run into is that the program loops from the beginning every time the player answers "yes", which means the number of tries always ends up being 1. I would like the program to count the number of tries until the user guesses the randint ( and for the randint to stay the same until the user guesses it) and then for the counter to restart as well as for the randint to change.
I limited the randint to (1,2) to make sure that the program is working
Thank you in advance.

```
import random
while True:

  guess = input(" Please choose a number 1 to 10")
  print("You chose " + guess)
  Num = random.randint(1, 2)
  count = 0
  # See if user input is even or odd number
  if (Num % 2) != 0:
      print("The number is not divisible by 2")
  # See if user input is equal to randint
  else:
      print("The number is divisible by 2")
  if int(guess) == Num:
      count = +1
      print("Correct! The correct number was" + " " + str(Num))
      print("It took you", count, "tries.")
  # See if user input is higher than randint
  elif int(guess) > Num:
      count = +1
      print("The number is lower. Please try again")
  # See if user input is lower than randint
  elif int(guess) < Num:
      count = +1
      print(" The correct number is higher. Please try again")
  play_again = input(" If you'd like to play again, please type 'yes'")
  if play_again == "yes":
      continue
  else:
      break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version to answer your questions:

> I would like the program to count the number of tries until the user guesses the randint ( and for the randint to stay the same until the user guesses it) and then for the counter to restart as well as for the randint to change.

I wasn't sure what you were going for by printing whether the random number is even or not so I've left that part out.  This simple version will loop until the guess is correct and provide the total number of guesses.  If the player chooses to continue, a new random number will be generated.

```
import random

play_again = "yes"
while play_again.lower() == "yes":
    guess = None
    count = 0
    num = random.randint(1, 10)
    while guess != num:
        # Asks for a guess until the guess matches the random number
        guess = int(input("Please choose a number 1 to 10: "))
        
        # Adds 1 to the guess count on each loop the player guesses incorrectly
        count += 1
    
    # Once the player guesses correctly, the inner while loop is broken 
    # and the below statement prints
    print(f"Congratulations, you guessed the number corrcectly in {count} guesses.  The numnber was {num}")

    # The player is asked if they'd like to play again.
    play_again = input("If you'd like to play again, please type 'yes' ")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```